# How to use abstract methods linked with enforced call for other methods

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am facing the following problem:

I defined an abstract class that contains the public generate, clone, etc. methods that must be implemented by the subclass. However I would like to ensure that when these public methods are called certain other methods are also executed within the abstract class.

An obvious solution would be to make a protected abstract method to be implemented and a public non-abstract method that calls the abstract one and all the other methods that I need.

For example:

```
abstract class Representation {

    public void generate(int variable) {
        myFunction();
        generateAbstract(variable);
    }

    protected abstract void generateAbstract(int variable);

    private void myFunction() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

My question is how to solve it a nicer way, or if this is the way to go how to name the function in a user-friendly way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it as you are doing it.  I would make the wrapper method either

1. `final` so I can't be blown away in a subclass, or
2. document the hell out of the methods, indicating that the abstract method **MUST** be called...

Answer (score 5):

Your way of solving this issue is so standard that it even has a name: it is called [*Template Method Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). The idea is to provide a public method that executes the steps of your algorithm at high-level, and use overrides of protected abstract methods in subclasses to deal with lower-level steps of the algorithm. This is the correct way of addressing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@dasblinkenlight's answer identifies the design pattern that addresses your problem: Template Method. [I like this Template Method link more](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/java/2) than the wikipedia entry that answer references. Also, I like answers with code examples:

```
// Demonstrate the template method design pattern
// straight out of GoF example
abstract class AbstractClass {
    // Final ensures extender does not override, but depends on your design
    final void templateMethod() {
        primitiveOperation1();
        primitiveOperation2();
    }

    // document extenders should keep as protected
    // so clients do not call directly
    protected abstract void primitiveOperation1();
    protected abstract void primitiveOperation2();
}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    @Override
    protected void primitiveOperation1() {
        System.out.println("ConcreteClass.primitiveOperation1()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void primitiveOperation2() {
        System.out.println("ConcreteClass.primitiveOperation2()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your suggested method is quite elegant enough. I've certainly solved the same problem in this way before. I'd possibly call your method `doGenerate()` (or something without the word `Abstract` in it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to ensure that `super.generate` is called. Since Java doesn't have a good mechanism for informing a class of when it has been subclassed (others like Ruby do), there's not much you can do to force a subclass that implements an abstract method to call another method.

Comment: You cannot ensure `super.generate` is called. I think the option described in the original post, plus @hvgotcodes addition of `final` is the answer. Anything else leaves the matter up to documentation and well behaving developers (shudder).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before, what you suggested is the correct approach according to the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). What is left is the naming issue. I would not call the function to be overwritten "generateAbstract" because when it is implemented it is not abstract anymore. I recommend something like "makeGenerate()" which reflects the original function and implies what it does.

```
abstract class Representation {

  public void generate(int variable) {
    myFunction();
    makeGenerate(variable);
  }

  protected abstract void generateAbstract(int variable);

  private void myFunction() {
    //do something
  }
}

public class ConcreteClass extends Representation {
  @Override
  protected void makeGenerate() {
    ...
  }
```